# My dough is too brown

Tags: baking, cookies, mixing

According to [this](http://centercutcook.com/perfect-chocolate-chip-cookies/) recipe, I did exactly what the author wrote. I ended up with a dough that was too wet and brown. I have several questions about to this recipe.

1. When the recipe calls for both white and brown sugar, am I suppose to add white sugar first, beat until incorporated, then mix in the brown sugar; or can I add them both in at the same time?.
2. Melted butter: I melted until it turned liquid. Mixing it with white and brown sugar resulted in a thick, dark brown liquid different from what I learned about using the creaming method. Did I melt my butter for too long?

The more I bake the more problems I find.

Comment: This is just a guess: perhaps the recipe calling for brown sugar means raw (brown) sugar? Another guess: perhaps you're using dark brown sugar (Muscovado) when it might be better to use a brown or light brown sugar.

Comment: "Brown sugar" is a US term. It  comes in light and dark varieties depending on how much molasses is added.   Since this recipe doesn't specify, either way will do depending on preference.

Comment: Cookie dough is often brown, what do you mean by "too brown"? As for too wet did you chill the dough?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can dump both sugars in together.

This recipe is not based on the creaming method.   Instead,  the butter is melted for a chewy cookie. 
You want the butter melted,  but not browned (although that may add flavor it is not called for in this recipe).

The  chilling and resting are essential for success.   During this time the starches will hydrate, the butter will chill,  and the dough will firm.

Your expectations from creaming method recipes do not apply, so don't worry that the dough doesn't seem exactly the same.  The color will be darker than you may be used to.   That is okay.

See also:  [What does an overnight chill do to cookie dough, that a 4 hour chill doesn't?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29270/what-does-an-overnight-chill-do-to-cookie-dough-that-a-4-hour-chill-doesnt)